# integrate Zkteco Device and SDK with my .net core application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sdk, zkteco

Hello I am new to Zkteco. I have a web app (which has users etc.), I need the device to communicate with SQL server and to get all the users/ visitors (etc.), but with SDK Standalone, I guess I’m not getting anything. So I decided to try the SDK Pull, but when
I use SDK Pull, I can’t trigger the event  OnAttTransactionEx  (which is really important to me, because when I trigger this, I can successfully get the info from device when a user is logged in successfully).

Comment: https://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html Check if this helps.

Comment: @Ramshri hello, thanks for answering. Actually I need to know, which sdk to use? And if I need to put the device as Pull Device, why  the event OnAttTransactionEx doesn't trigger?

Comment: It is because of, i believe, a dirty business. Same model from another country may support OnAttTranactionEx, but in the recently released devices from India, the event is not triggered in the most of the devices. Zk India, disables it intentionally, or while making Indian version of firmware restriction, they introduced this bug. Sad things is, you cannot get the support from the manufacturer, for this issue. So you have to go with x min polling to pull the newest records.

Comment: What ZKTeco device are you using to test?

Comment: @angrinessfap i'm using SpeedFace -V5